# Error: Undeclared identifier: 'OutputDebugString'

Tags: delphi, outputdebugstring, undeclared-identifier

I use OutputDebugString in my Delphi Code, but I receive the error:

> Error: Undeclared identifier: 'OutputDebugString'

Which package is this OutputDebugString in?

Comment: Useful tip in future; In a unit that has it working, Ctrl-Click and it will find the unit containing the symbol. And in Delphi recent versions, F1 on OutputDebugString might get you some help too.

Comment: Instead of Ctrl-Cick, I prefer to use "Find definition" from the context menu (or is it "Find declaration"?). I keep forgetting all those key-key and key-mouse combinations.

Comment: ...or hover your mouse cursor over the symbol and see the help insight (in a unit that has it working).

Comment: Personally I prefer Windows Search 4. At the beginning you just need to explain it that pas-files are "plain text" and point it to directories which should be indexed.

Comment: @Torbins - I prefer source searching too, because some classes are defined in more than one namespace - for instance TBitmap; it's in [Graphics.pas](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TBitmap) as well as in [Windows.pas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but they mean totally different thing. There I wouldn't rely on the methods mentioned above; even if they are much more faster than this searching. But hey, isn't there some tool, some class explorer for this, something in CnPack or another IDE extension ?

Comment: If not it would be fine to create one. As a starting version would be enough to search *.pas (*.inc and whatever) files in predefined directories for `TClassYoureLookingFor =`

Comment: Windows Search 4 is extremely fast. I never had a need of something faster.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's declared in the `Windows` unit.

Answer (score 1):

In windows unit in Winapi namespace:

```
uses
   Winapi.Windows;
```

How to find the unit of a specific command:

- Through Find Definition command in the context menu
- Through Help Insight information invoked by hovering the mouse
- Or just use Windows Search or a popular search tool